# Why does Rust generate LLVM IR in an architecture-specific way and use empty arrays for mutable static variables?

Tags: arrays, rust, architecture, llvm, endianness

```rust
struct Point<'a> {
    x: i32,
    caption: &'a str,
    y: i32,
}

static mut global_var: Point = Point {
    x: 123,
    y: 344,
    caption: "123",
};
```

The corresponding LLVM IR is:

```
%Point = type
{
    [0 x i64],
    { [0 x i8]*, i64 },
    [0 x i32],
    i32,
    [0 x i32],
    i32,
    [0 x i32]
}

@_ZN5hello10global_var17h76c725a117a5fdc6E = internal global
    <{ i8*, [16 x i8] }>
    <{
       i8* getelementptr inbounds
       (
           <{ [3 x i8] }>,
           <{ [3 x i8] }>* @6,
           i32 0,
           i32 0,
           i32 0
       ),
       [16 x i8] c"\03\00\00\00\00\00\00\00{\00\00\00X\01\00\00"
    }>,
    align 8,
    !dbg !330
```

There are two interesting points that I am trying to find the answers for:

1. Why are there empty arrays in the type definition of `%Point`? It doesn't seem to be a Pascal-style array here.
2. Why is the `global_var` initialized in an indirect and architecture-specific way (the contents of the integers are filled with a little endian buffer directly), since LLVM IR code is supposed to be architecturally independent?

If possible, can we get LLVM IR code with those initializations in a more readable style?

---

Update to response some comments:

1. Why c"\03\00\00\00\00\00\00\00{\00\00\00X\01\00\00" is an initialization of the struct?

If we write down the hexadecimal representation of the string, we can find it is exactly how i64 3, i32 123 and i23 344 is stored in a little-endian architecture.

2. My rust version is 1.41.0-nightly (19a0de242 2019-12-12). The LLVM IR is generated by `cargo rustc -- --emit=llvm-bc` and then using `llvm-dis` to disassembly.

Comment: I don't even see how initializer in the IR relates to the source code you posted.

Comment: The IR language is independent of architecture, and code that operates *on* IR is generally portable, but code written *in* IR is almost always target-specific.

Comment: Interesting, [rustc's output](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fe93127d677da45f004158b6d904c72a) is totally unlike [Clang's](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06f9055408ec31d6).

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe what version of Rust you are using and how you are generating the LLVM IR. When I use the playground to view the LLVM IR for the code you provided using Rust 1.40 in debug mode, I don't even see a type created.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: this answer is an educated guess.*

**TL;DR: I guess that explicit padding arrays and explicit initialization are intended to avoid leaving any uninitialized byte behind, and the undefined behavior this results in.**

---

#### A Detour through C

It's important to realize that LLVM inherits much of its low-level semantics from C. Its first and foremost front-end is Clang, after all, and this has shaped much of it.

When Clang lowers a `struct` to LLVM IR, it confidently leaves LLVM to figure out the padding [link](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06f9055408ec31d6).

Thus:

```c
    struct A
    {
        int a;
        struct { char const* ptr; size_t len; } str;
        char c;
    };

    A const GLOBAL{ 1, { "hello", 5 }, 'c' };
```

is lowered to:

```
%struct.A = type { i32, %struct.anon, i8 }
%struct.anon = type { i8*, i64 }


@_ZL6GLOBAL = internal constant %struct.A
{
    i32 1,
    %struct.anon
    {
        i8* getelementptr inbounds ([6 x i8], [6 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0),
        i64 5
    },
    i8 99
}, align 8

@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [6 x i8] c"hello\00", align 1
```

This means that the padding bytes are left uninitialized, and in typical C fashion reading uninitialized bytes is Undefined Behavior.

This means that bit-copying a struct with uninitialized padding bytes is Undefined Behavior, and while `memcpy` calls (being lowered to intrinsics) seem not to be affected, I am not aware of any provision in the C standard that gives `memcpy` a pass...

---

#### Back to Rust

Rust takes a strong stance whenever Undefined Behavior comes up:

- There should be no Undefined Behavior in safe Rust<sup>1</sup>.
- There should be as little Undefined Behavior in unsafe Rust.

Leaving behind uninitialized padding bytes, and tripping up users performing a bit-copy, very much seems like an unnecessary source of Undefined Behavior:

There does not seem to be much (if any) performance benefit: with Rust being free to rearrange struct members, and compacting structs, there are generally very few padding bytes (only a few trailing ones).

My guess, therefore, is that rustc explicitly specifies padding arrays<sup>2</sup> and explicitly initializes them, so as to avoid leaving any uninitialized padding byte behind.

<sup>1</sup> *There is, still. For example due to LLVM considering that converting a `float` to an `int` is UB if the value doesn't fit, or LLVM considering that an infinite loop with no side-effect is UB -- both inherited from C. It's a work in progress.*

<sup>2</sup> *This does not provide a rationale for the 0-sized arrays, those seem entirely superfluous to me.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! According to discussions posted on Reddit, those empty arrays are likely to be used for alignment padding. I will invite them to also put an answer in this question. https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/et2i62/why_the_global_variables_in_llvm_ir_is_generated/

Comment: @zsf222: I agree that the arrays are likely due to padding generation, padding is filled with arrays, and the absence of padding simply leads to a 0-sized array. I very much doubt that alignment is involved, though, the members that follow the arrays are already aligned, there's no need to "force" the alignment further with empty arrays.